# Display model and its relations

Tags: python, django, django-models

My models.py is as follows:

```
from django.db import models

class Book(models.Model):
    book_id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True,unique=True)
    book_name=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    author_name=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    publisher_name=models.CharField(max_length=40)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%d %s %s %s" % (self.book_id,self.book_name, self.author_name,self.publisher_name)


class Author(models.Model):
    author_id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    email = models.EmailField()
    age=models.IntegerField()
    book=models.ForeignKey(Book)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%d %s %s' % (self.author_id,self.first_name, self.last_name)
```

and my views.py is this:

```
def index(request):

    books = Book.objects.all()
    context={'books':books}
    return render(request,'index.html', context)
```

The above views.py displays contents in the Book class, but I am not able to display the contents in the author table. My requirement is to display both contents merged in a single page. Please help me do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**models.py**

```
class Book(models.Model):
    book_name=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    author_name=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    publisher_name=models.CharField(max_length=40)
    author=models.ForeignKey(Author)

    def __unicode__(self):
        ..........

class Author(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    email = models.EmailField()
    age=models.IntegerField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        ........

    def books(self):
        return Book.objects.filter(author=self)
```

**views.py**

```
def index(request):
    authors = Author.objects.all()
    context={'authors':authors}
    return render(request,'index.html', context)
```

**template**

```
{% for author in authors %}
    Author: {{author.first_name}} {{author.last_name}}<br/>
    Email: {{author.email}}
    Age: {{author.age}}
    Books:
        {% for book in author.books %}
            .......
        {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Books:
        {% for book in author.books %}
            .......
        {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}

Comment: yes, why? that explain one author have many books. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Well, it doesn't look like you set up your models correctly first off. Django handles ids if none is provided so you don't need `author_id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)`. Also, shouldn't a book have an author, not an author have a book? If you do it correctly, you don't need `author_name=models.CharField(max_length=30)` either, cause you would have a foreign key to your Author model which has their name.

Once you set them up correctly, it is very easy to access the data in your template. For example, you would use `book.author.first_name` in your template to get the name of the book's author.

---

```
from django.db import models

class Author(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    email = models.EmailField()
    age = models.IntegerField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%d %s %s' % (self.pk, self.first_name, self.last_name)

class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author)
    publisher_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"%d %s %s %s" % (self.pk, self.name, self.author.name, self.publisher_name)
```

### template

```
{% for book in books %}
    ...
    {% for author in book.author_set %}
        ...
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```